# LASSO with glmnet, year dummies and penalty.factor, different results than with demeaned data

Tags: panel-data, glmnet, lasso-regression

Not sure if this is a question for Cross Validated or Stackoverflow, will try both.

I am running a LASSO using glmnet. I have panel data. I first run `cv.glmnet()` to select the best lambda, then I run `glmnet()` with `lambda.min`. I run this with two versions:

1. With year demeaned data.
2. With year dummies and `penalty.factor` set so that it does not drop them (  `= 0` for dummies).

When running it with year dummies, it drops all variables, while with demeaned data, it keeps 13 variables.

Can someone explain me the theory behind this?